# ReferenceError: describe is not defined Karma jasmine angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to write some test with jamsine and karma in an ionic project V2.
I added the packages but i dont know why i still have the probleme" describe is not defined" 
Could any one help me please?
Thanks

karma.conf.js:

```
 // Karma configuration
 // Generated on Thu Apr 19 2018 18:27:54 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure 
 d’été))

module.exports = function(config) {
 config.set({

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
],


// list of files / patterns to exclude
exclude: [
],


// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma- 
preprocessor
preprocessors: {
},


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],


// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || 
config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file 
 changes autoWatch: true,


// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma- 
launcher
browsers: ['Chrome'],


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: false,

// Concurrency level
// how many browser should be started simultaneous
concurrency: Infinity
})
```

}

I tried to change my karma.conig.js but still have the same problem
any idea please?

Comment: Install jasmine typings `npm install @types/jasmine --save-dev`

Comment: i already did it. but that's did not change any thing

Answer (score 3):

You need to install jasmine typings

`npm install @types/jasmine --save-dev`

You also must include them in your `tsconfig.spec.json`

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc/spec",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["jasmine", "node"],
  },
  "files": ["test.js"],
  "include": ["**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": [
    "**/e2e/*.ts",
    "**/*.e2e-spec.ts",
    "**/*.po.ts",
    "node_modules",
    "tmp"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Tomasz kula i dont have a ts.config.json do you mean karma.conf .js?